# Proposal: Add new tag "advanced-wireless"

Tags: discussion, tagging

The [aws](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aws) says it means "Advanced Wireless Systems".

There are however only 13 question with this tag, and all except possibly two are written obviously thinking it's Amazon Web Services.

Option 1: Create [advanced-wireless](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advanced-wireless), migrate any questions over, create [amazon-web-services](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services) and migrate those questions, delete [aws](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aws) as ambiguous.

Option 2: Create [advanced-wireless](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advanced-wireless), migrate any questions over, re-describe [aws](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aws) as Amazon Web Services.

Option 3: Leave tag definitions alone, remove [aws](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aws) from questions related to Amazon Web Services.

Option 4: Do nothing.

I prefer options 1 and 2 (in that order).  3 seems unhelpful.  4 leaves a dozen questions apparently mis-tagged.

What think you all?

Jonathan.

Comment: I migrated the [tag:aws] to [tag:advanced-wireless-services]. People can create [tag:aws] for Amazon Web Services, which is mostly off-topic here, anyway.

Comment: thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing a tag will not stop people from creating it again, anyone can add any tag (even if it does not exist) to a question. So option 1 and 3 will only work for a short while and then the [aws](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aws) tag will pop up again.

I prefer option 2, I think [aws](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aws) is associated more often with Amazon Web Services than with Advanced Wireless Services, but that may be the bubble I'm living in.

Comment: Ron's already moved it to `advanced-wireless-services`, and we shall see if AWS returns; I suspect you are correct.

Comment: @jonathanjo, there is a "shortcut" for tags. You can do `[tag:advanced-wireless-services]` to get a tag like Teun did in his answer, or a link like I have in my comment above.

Comment: The AWS tag absolutely should refer to Amazon-Web-Services... I tagged several questions with it to jump-start things